# difference between lines in the same column using AWK

Tags: csv, awk

I want to compare the lines of the same column in a csv file and keep only the lines that respect the following conditions

1.if the first pattern is the same as the one in the previous line and

2.the difference between the values in the second column equal abs(1)

for example if I have this lines

```
aaaa;12
aaaa;13
bbbb;11
bbbb;9
cccc;9
cccc;8
```

I will keep only

```
aaaa;12
aaaa;13
cccc;9
cccc;8
```

Comment: You forgot to post your code. StackOverflow is about helping people fix their code. It's not a free coding service. Any code is better than no code at all. commonly people use a variable name `prev` which they test against the current line (`$0`). Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given:

```
$ echo "$test" 
aaaa;12
aaaa;13
bbbb;11
bbbb;9
cccc;9
cccc;8
```

You can do something like:

```
$ echo "$test" | awk -F ";" 'function abs(v) {return v < 0 ? -v : v} $1==l1 && abs($2-l2)==1 {print l1 FS l2 RS $0} {l1=$1;l2=$2}'
aaaa;12
aaaa;13
cccc;9
cccc;8
```

Answer (score 2):

The logic would work this way:

- If the previous pattern is not equal to this pattern, then remember the this pattern and this value as the new "previous", and move to the next line.
- Otherwise, if the difference between the previous value and this value equals 1 or -1 (awk does not have an abs() function) then print the previous pattern and value and print this line.

Take a stab at translating that into code, and come back when you have questions.